# MVC Razor - Get Checkbox values from object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So the model for my view is any object.  In the view, I create the Metadata and iterate through all the properties.  Each displayable property gets a checkbox, like so:

```
ModelMetadata mm = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, this.Model.GetType());
foreach(ModelMetadata prop in mm.Properties.Where(t=> t.ShowForDisplay))
{
@Html.CheckBox(prop.PropertyName, ViewBag.CheckedColumns.Contains(prop.PropertyName))@Html.Raw(prop.DisplayName ?? prop.PropertyName)
}
```

So some of these checkboxes are checked and some are not.  When I click on my ActionLink I'd like to be able to determine which are and which are not checked.  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: you have too much logic in your view, you have to clean it up, put all that junk in the controller not the view. Then you want to use a for loop. Can you post your model definition

Comment: My model is any given object.  I'm trying to do this in a generic fashion as I need to repeat this same thing for many different objects in my project.